# Creating a link to an NFS share in K3s Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I'm very new to Kubernetes, and trying to get node-red running on a small cluster of raspberry pi's
I happily managed that, but noticed that once the cluster is powered down, next time I bring it up, the flows in node-red have vanished.

So, I've create a NFS share on a freenas box on my local network and can mount it from another RPI, so I know the permissions work.

However I cannot get my mount to work in a kubernetes deployment.

Any help as to where I have gone wrong please?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-red
  labels:
    app: node-red
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-red
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-red
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-red
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
          name: node-red-ui
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: node-red-data
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: TZ
          value: Europe/London
      volumes:
         - name: node-red-data
      nfs:
         server: 192.168.1.96
         path: /mnt/Pool1/ClusterStore/nodered
```

The error I am getting is

> ```
> error: error validating "node-red-deploy.yml": error validating data: 
> ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "nfs" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if 
> you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
> ```

New Information

I now have the following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: clusterstore-nodered
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /mnt/Pool1/ClusterStore/nodered
    server: 192.168.1.96 
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: clusterstore-nodered-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Now when I start the deployment it waits at pending forever and I see the following the the events for the PVC

Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                   From                                                                                                Message
  ----     ------                ----                  ----                                                                                                -------
  Normal   WaitForFirstConsumer  5m47s (x7 over 7m3s)  persistentvolume-controller                                                                         waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
  Normal   Provisioning          119s (x5 over 5m44s)  rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-58fb86bdfd-rtcls_506528ac-afd0-11ea-930d-52d0b85bb2c2  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/clusterstore-nodered-claim"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    119s (x5 over 5m44s)  rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-58fb86bdfd-rtcls_506528ac-afd0-11ea-930d-52d0b85bb2c2  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "local-path": Only support ReadWriteOnce access mode

Normal   ExternalProvisioning  92s (x19 over 5m44s)  persistentvolume-controller
                                                                         waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rancher.io/local-path" or manually created by system administrator

I assume that this is becuase I don't have a nfs provider, in fact if I do kubectl get storageclass I only see local-path

New question, how do I a add a storageclass for NFS?  A little googleing around has left me without a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved the issue.   Kubernetes tutorials are really esoteric and missing lots of assumed steps.

My problem was down to k3s on the pi only shipping with a local-path storage provider.

I finally found a tutorial that installed an nfs client storage provider, and now my cluster works!

[This was the tutorial I found the information in.](https://www.freshbrewed.science/getting-started-with-k3s/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

**In the stated Tutorial there are basically these steps to fulfill:**

1.

```
showmount -e 192.168.1.XY
```

to check if the share is reachable from outside the NAS

2.

```
helm install nfs-provisioner stable/nfs-client-provisioner --set nfs.server=192.168.1.**XY** --set nfs.path=/samplevolume/k3s --set image.repository=quay.io/external_storage/nfs-client-provisioner-arm
```

Whereas you replace the IP with your NFS Server and the NFS path with your specific Path on your synology (both should be visible from your ***showmount -e IP*** command

**Update 23.02.2021**
It seems that you have to use another Chart and Image too:

```
helm install nfs-subdir-external-provisioner nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner --set nfs.server=192.168.1.**XY** --set nfs.path=/samplevolume/k3s --set image.repository=gcr.io/k8s-staging-sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
```

3. kubectl get storageclass

To check if the storageclass now exists

4.

```
kubectl patch storageclass nfs-client -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}' && kubectl patch storageclass local-path -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"false"}}}'
```

To configure the new Storage class as "default". Replace nfs-client and local-path with what kubectl get storageclass tells

5.

```
kubectl get storageclass
```

Final check, if it's marked as "default"

Answer (score 1):

This is a validation error pointing at the very last part of your Deployment yaml, therefore making it an invalid object. It looks like you've made a mistake with indentations. It should look more like this:

```
  volumes:
  - name: node-red-data
    nfs:
      server: 192.168.1.96
      path: /mnt/Pool1/ClusterStore/nodered
```

Also, as you are new to Kubernetes, I strongly recommend getting familiar with the concepts of [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and its claims. PVs are volume plugins like [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/), but have a lifecycle independent of any individual Pod that uses the PV.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try re-writing to get the indentation better.  I hadn;t realised it was important (assumed whitespacing).

I have tried to do it with Persistant Volumes, When I've tried it with the NFS share, it just wont schedule the pod, it sits at pending forever.

I changed to local-path and while that worked, as soon as I test failover, by disconnecting the node running node-red, it sits at terminating, and wont reschedule on a new node,  I assume becuase the new node doesn't have the same data as the old node in it's local path.

Comment: @PeterPage Wrong indentation is a common beginner error, just keep that in mind while working with yaml files. I see that you also solved your second issue. If you need more assistance feel free to ask another question and the community will try to help you out.